# How to edit latest google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to edit coordinate. such as input logitude and latitute, but I dont know how to link between javasciprt and html.

when I fill in input(Textbox HTML) latitude and logitute, It will display directly map on html page. Thanks for your reply

Regards,
Fizul

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAVXRyUtndMPwJqkRUXFpmk9BLIFxpsj24">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { ***lat: 4.414022, lng: 101.379503}***,
          zoom: 15
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>



  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<form>
<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat"></input>
<input type="text" name="long" id="long"></input>
<input type="submit" >
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking to recenter your map based on the new lat/long, then

```
map.setCenter([some lat/lng object]); // resets the senter of your map
```

New lat/lng objects are easily created too

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(39.5, -98.3);
```

so:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(39.5, -98.3);
map.setCenter(center);
```

or to be a little cleaner

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(39.5, -98.3));
```

So now all you need it to update your map object on submitting your form

(Basic click event on a button etc)